# How to redirect htaccess http://sub.domain.com/abc/123 to http://domain.com/abc/123 but http://sub.domain.com still running

Tags: .htaccess

Please help me!

How to redirect htaccess **sub.domain.com/abc/123** to **domain.com/abc/123** but **sub.domain.com** still running

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about website configuration, not programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^abc/123$ http://domain.com/abc/123
```

Comment: thanks you, but, abc/123 is not static folder.

Comment: If you want to redirect all sub domain folders to domain, try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1`. I cannnot help you if I don't know what you realy want.